# CodeIgniter query syntax error

Tags: debugging, codeigniter, syntax

I am facing a syntax issue with a CodeIgniter database query. Can't figure out what's wrong.

```
$query = $this->db->query("
   INSERT IGNORE INTO ".$table." (email, lang, ip_address) 
   VALUES (".$this->db->escape($_POST['email']).", ".$this->db->escape($lang).", ".$this->input->ip_address().")");
```

I am also looking for a way to output what the query looks like once the placeholders are replaced, as I am little confused with CodeIgniter debugging options.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you are not escaping the strings that you're trying to input into the database. The query you've posted would evaluate to something like:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name (email, lang, ip_address) 
    VALUES (email@email.com, en, 192.168.0.1)
");
```

This will throw an error as the strings in VALUES are not properly escaped. Instead of the query you're running you should use something like:

```
$query = $this->db->query("
    INSERT IGNORE INTO ".$table." (email, lang, ip_address) 
    VALUES ('".$this->db->escape($_POST['email'])."', '".$this->db->escape($lang)."', '".$this->input->ip_address()."')
");
```

Note the new ' characters around each string.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

for retrieving the query runned.

so then check if the query is well formatted.

Answer (score 0):

To know what query you are passing to your database. Use below statement and to insert data into the database. Please follow the below procedure.

```
  echo $this->db->last_query();

     $data = array(
           'email' =>  $this->db->escape($_POST['email']),
           'lang' = >  $this->db->escape($lang),
           'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address(),
     );

 Call your model function $this->model->insert_function_name($data);

Your model function in your model file
public function insert_function_name($data)

  {
         $this->db->insert($table_name,$data);
    return $this->db->insert_id();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** : your query was **missing single quotes** to the string type of value like email, lang and ip

```
$query = $this->db->query("
   INSERT IGNORE INTO ".$table." (email, lang, ip_address) 
   VALUES ('".$this->db->escape($_POST['email'])."', '".$this->db->escape($lang)."', '".$this->input->ip_address()."')");
```

Comment: good, if you consider this is the right answer please select it as a answer.